# i want to calculate data of python written in a file but i don't know what to do

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

**File data:**

```
nims 12 100
dettol 42 100
pycharm 30 500
getz 25 455
```

**Code:**

```
cart=[]
with open("C:\\Users\\azhar\\PycharmProjects\\final\\data.txt", "r") as T:
   for a in range(0,20):
       cart.append(T.readline())
   print(cart)
```

**Description**

here nims is a medecine name and 12 is the quantity of that medicine and 100 is price per quantity i want to calculate bill and want to less the quantity so what should i do for this???

Comment: what do you mean by `want to less the quantity `  ?

Comment: if we buy one quanitiy then we will less them from the orignal quantity as nims has 12 quantity when we will buy one then we will less 1 quanity and remaining will be 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all we iterate over each line in the file and assuming that each line has only 3 entries separated by space, we extract name, quantity and price of each commodity , and these are stored as strings, to apply mathematical operations we convert them to integers (you can convert to float if you want to ) and then multiply quantity with the price adding them all up in the total_price.

```
total_bill = 0
with open("C:\\Users\\azhar\\PycharmProjects\\final\\data.txt", "r") as T:
   for line in T.readlines():
       name, qty, price = line.split()
       total_bill+= int(qty)*int(price)
print total_bill
```

Comment: If that worked out you can Green check my answer or upvote to help the further users if they face the same issue ?

Comment: can you please help me about how to update quanitiy after decrement of 1?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot incorporate that feature in this script alone, you will need to create a new script for that because form this script you cannot infer as which item is sold out , So, the workflow of that script could be simply you take input from the user using `raw_input()` and then the quantity you want to decrement, and then perform the relevant action